# Message to partition assignment, ordering and partition number resizing

Tags: apache-kafka

As I understand, if I use keyed messages in one of my topics, the kafka partitioner will always send messages with the same key to the same partition and this will ensure the ordering of that particular set of messages.

Also the default partitioner will initially make the decision to which partition to send a message, based on the number of partitions available to that particular topic. Something like messageKeyHash % numberOfPartitions.

My question is, if I have a topic with let's **5 partitions**, and send **3 messages** that have the **key A** and they are all assigned to **partition 0**, and later I **increase the number of partitions** for that topic from 5 to 5+x, will kafka "remember" that messages with key A are supposed to go to partition 0 or the partitioner may send messages with key A to another partition?

In other words: **If I increase the number of partitions of a topic, at runtime, will I lose the ordering guarantees for a particular key in that topic?**

If yes, how can I solve this problem? Should always over-partition if I need ordering guarantees? Should I implement a custom partitioner (I do'nt see how)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you increase the number of partitions you will lose such guarantee because messages with key A could go a different partition and not to the partition 0 anymore.
In general it's good thing to over-partition or at least knowing the best number of partitions when you are going to create the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem two ways

1) By creating your own custom partitioner that will always resolve the same key to the same partition, even when more topic partitions are created.

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html

2) By creating a new topic with more partitions than the original, copying all the messages from the old topic to the new one, and then doing all new publishing to the new topic.